# How to get active users per page in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters, google-realtime-api

I am new to Google Analytics, and I am using Analytics real time API to get real time data. Now I am trying to get "Top Active Page" section which appears on the "Overview" link in "Real time" menu in "analytic.google.com" site. In that "Top Active Page" section, it shows how many active users are on each page. Which metric and dimension do I use to get active user for each page? The percentage which appears. I can manage as it shows from total active users, and how many percentage of users are on which page.

Comment: I try to get data for referral data for analytic, and I get that data, but actually I want data for only social media referral data say Facebook. So how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- metrics = "rt:activeUsers"
- dimensions = "rt:pagePath"

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works as I expect from it.

Comment: I try to get data for referral data for analytic, and I get that data, but actually I want data for only social media referral data say Facebook. So how can I get it?